# Filtering by custom column make an error

Tags: magento-2.1, grid

I need a new "dynamic" column in my custom grid so
I created grid, I extend `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult` and I add in `_beforeLoad()` new column:

```
const NEW_COLUMN = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE group_id=main_table.group_id)";

 $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(['new_column' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(self::NEW_COLUMN)])
```

Sorting by this column work perfectly, but when I try to use a filter I got an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'new_column' in 'where clause'

**Here are SQL queries:**

Grid query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE a.group_id=main_table.group_id) AS `new_column` FROM `main_base_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`type` = '0') LIMIT 20
```

Filter query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `main_base_table` AS `main_table` WHERE (`new_column` >= '1') AND (`new_column` <= '3') AND (`type` = '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass table alias with group_id like below example

```
const NEW_COLUMN = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE alias.group_id=main_table.group_id)";
```

**alias = Your table alias**

Comment: Still the same.  In error message, I see only main query. I believe there might be a problem

Grid query:
`SELECT main_table.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE a.group_id=main_table.group_id) AS new_column FROM main_base_table AS main_table WHERE (type = '0') LIMIT 20`

Filter query:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main_base_table AS main_table WHERE (new_column >= '1') AND (new_column <= '3') AND (type = '0')`

Comment: You need to also add a.group_id in grid column layout.